# Laravel function controller validation error

Tags: php, laravel

I have validation issue when I tried to apply the coupon code.
I have to apply on **4** condition

1. If I applied the correct coupon from the database then it will be fine.
2. If I applied the correct coupon again from the database then it will be
   show the message '**This Coupon Have Already Used**'.
3. If I just directly key in button (blank value) it will show the message '**Please Insert
   The Coupon Code**'
4. But the problem is what I key in the wrong coupon code, I need to
   have '**Wrong Coupon Code Entered**' message displayed

Below is the controller part for the function:-

```
public function checkCoupon(Request $res)
{
    $code = $res->code;
    $check = DB::table('coupons')
        ->where('coupon_code',$code)
        ->get();
    if(count($check)=="1") {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $check_used = DB::table('used_coupons')
            ->where('user_id', $user_id)
            ->where('coupon_id', $check[0]->id)
            ->count();

        if($check_used=="0"){
            $used_add = DB::table('used_coupons')
                ->insert([
                    'coupon_id' => $check[0]->id,
                    'user_id' => $user_id
                ]);
            $insert_cart_total = DB::table('cart_total')
                ->insert([
                    'cart_total' => Cart::total(),
                    'discount' => $check[0]->discount,
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'gtotal' =>  Cart::total() - (Cart::total() * $check[0]->discount)/100,
                ]);
        }
        else{
        ?>
            <div class="alert alert-warning">This Coupon Have Already Used</div>
        <?php
        }
    }
    else if($code==$check){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong Coupon Code Entered</div>
    <?php }
    else{
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">Please Insert The Coupon Code </div>
    <?php }
}
```

**JS** file for apply **coupon** function button:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){           
  $('#coupon_btn').click(function(){
                var coupon_id = $('#coupon_id').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:'{{url('/checkCoupon')}}',
                    data: 'code=' + coupon_id,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#cartTotal').html(res);
                    }
                })
            });
        });
```

View File

```
         <div class="cart-total" >
                <h4>Total Amount</h4>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Sub Total</td>
                        <td>$ <?php echo Cart::subtotal(); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tax (%)</td>
                        <td>$ <?php echo Cart::tax(); ?></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td>Grand Total new</td>
                        <td>$ <?php echo Cart::total(); ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Discount(%) </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $disnew; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Grand Total (After discount) </td>
                        <td>$ <?php echo $gtnew; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" class="btn update btn-block" style="color: white;font-weight: bold;" value="Continue Shopping">
                <a href="<?php echo url('checkout') ?>" class="btn check_out btn-block"  style="color: white;font-weight: bold;">Checkout</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: HTML code printed directly to the screen in controller??? Seriously???

Comment: actually the view blade file is fine. just the validation I may make some mistake, so need someone expert who will try to solve this issue. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check used coupons better to use **exists** instead of **count**.

To get coupon better to use **first** instead of **get** (first - return first element, you dont need to use index on collection)

I think, in this situation better to use returns. Code and logic looks clearly.

```
public function checkCoupon(Request $res)
{
    $code = $res->input('code');
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    if(!$code){
        return ['error' => '<div class="alert alert-danger">Please Insert The Coupon Code </div>'];
    }

    $coupon = DB::table('coupons')
            ->where('coupon_code', $code)
            ->first();

    if(!$coupon) {
        return ['error' => '<div class="alert alert-danger">Wrong Coupon Code Entered</div>'];
    }

    $isUsed = DB::table('used_coupons')
            ->where('user_id', $userId)
            ->where('coupon_id', $coupon->id)
            ->exists();

    if($isUsed){
        return ['error' => '<div class="alert alert-warning">This Coupon Have Already Used</div>'];
    }

    DB::table('used_coupons')
        ->insert([
            'coupon_id' => $coupon->id,
            'user_id' => $userId
        ]);

    DB::table('cart_total')
        ->insert([
            'cart_total' => Cart::total(),
            'discount' => $coupon->discount,
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'gtotal' =>  Cart::total() - (Cart::total() * $coupon->discount)/100,
    ]);

    return [
        'subtotal' => Cart::subtotal(),
        'total' => Cart::total()
    ];
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $('#coupon_btn').click(function(){
        var coupon_id = $('#coupon_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{url('/checkCoupon')}}',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {code: coupon_id},
            success:function(res){
                if(res.error){
                    $('...error_selector...').html(res.error);
                } else {
                    $('...total_selector...').html(res.total);
                    $('...subtotal_selector...').html(res.subtotal);
                }

            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: may i know is that possible to insert <?php echo ?> inside the return ?

Comment: For what? It will only print <?php echo ?> as text without execution.

Comment: let say I want to <?php echo Cart::subtotal(); ?> the Cart is the model. I wish to print out the subtotal of cart model.

Comment: I think you can add "return Cart::subtotal();" in the end of method.

Comment: can you briefly describe how to make it?

Comment: tried but not works. because I want to show the subtotal and total as well. so should be insert the code inside <div>

Comment: I have update the JS file for the coupon button, please check.

Comment: can you check my view file as well? Because it need to show the table row for subtotal, tax and total in condition 2,3,4. If will display the discount row if insert the correct coupon code.

Comment: Is it blade template engine?